# Getting error when trying scrapping webpage in in-line editor GoogleDialogflow

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to scrap a webpage from the inline editor of dialogflow but getting this error from diagnostic:

"message": Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE, State: URL_UNREACHABLE, Reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx, HTTP status code: 500.

And in my firebase logs get I this error log:

dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment
Error:No responses defined for platform: DIALOGFLOW_CONSOLE
at V2Agent.sendResponses_ (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js:243:13)
at WebhookClient.send_ (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:505:17)
at promise.then (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:316:38)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

My code:

```
var rq = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
  function giveProject(agent){
    const type_project = agent.parameters.type_project;
    let url;
    if(type_project == null){
      url = 'https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub';
    }else url = 'https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/search?q=' + type_project;
    let list_projects = [];
    rq(url, function(error,
            response, html)  {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log("in");
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);
                const projects = $('.mobile-scroll-row-item');
                projects.each((i, el) => {
                    const title = $(el).find('.thumb-inner').find('.project-link-with-ref').text();
                    const description = $(el).find('.thumb-image').find('.thumb-image-inner-top').text();
                    const imageUrl = $(el).find('.project-thumb-img').attr('data-async-src');
                    const urlProject = $(el).find('a').attr('href');
                    if (imageUrl != null) {
                        list_projects.push({
                            title: title,
                            description: description,
                            imageUrl: imageUrl,
                            urlProject: urlProject
                        });
                    } else {
                        list_projects.push({
                            title: title,
                            description: description,
                            urlProject: urlProject
                        });
                    }
                });
              let project = list_projects[getRandomNumber(list_projects.length)];
              //agent response
            }else agent.add('error:'+error);
        });
  }
```

My package json:

```
{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1",
    "request":"2.88.2",
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, on the free '[Spark Plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)', Firebase Functions does not allow outbound networking. This means your attempt to make a request to Arduino will fail as shown.

To fix this, you'll need to upgrade your project to Firebase's Pay-as-you-go 'Blaze Plan'.